# Reversible-jump MCMC for knot selection

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, reversible-jump

Let $\{Z(\boldsymbol s):\boldsymbol s\in\mathcal D\}$ denote the Gaussian spatial random field on a spatial domain $\mathcal D\subset\mathbb R^2$.
Suppose that at $N$ locations, we have observations $\mathbf Z=\{Z(\boldsymbol s_1),\ldots, Z(\boldsymbol s_N)\}$. Consider the Bayesian hierarchical model:

\begin{equation}\label{OurMethod}
\begin{aligned}
&\textbf{Data Model: } &\mathbf Z\mid\boldsymbol\delta,\tau^2\sim\mathcal N(\boldsymbol\Phi\boldsymbol\delta,\tau^2\mathcal I) \\
&\textbf{Process Model: } &\boldsymbol\delta \mid\tau^2\sim\mathcal N(\textbf 0, \tau^2\mathcal I)\\
&\textbf{Parameter Model: } & \tau^2\sim p(\tau^2), \mathcal K\sim p(\mathcal K),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $\boldsymbol\Phi$ is an $N\times r$ basis function matrix where the $r$ basis functions have corresponding knots $\mathcal K=\{\boldsymbol k_1,\ldots\boldsymbol k_r\}$.

I wish to employ a reversible-jump MCMC (RJMCMC) algorithm to select the number and the placement of the knot locations. We take the number of knots $r$ to be random, from some countable set $\mathcal S$. $\mathcal M_{r}$ denotes the model with exactly $r$ knots and $\mathcal K(r) = \{\boldsymbol k_1,\ldots, \boldsymbol k_{r}\}$ denotes the knot locations. We shall generate samples from the joint posterior of $(r, \mathcal K(r))$. To account for the varying dimensionality, we must develop appropriate reversible jump moves. For this problem, possible transitions are to add a knot (birth step), delete a knot (death step), or move a knot. These independent move types are randomly chosen with probability $b_{r}$ for move $r$ to $r +1$ (birth step), $d_{r}$ for move $r$ to $r -1$ (death step), and $\eta_{r}$ for the move step. These probabilities must satisfy $b_{r} + d_{r} + \eta_{r} = 1$. Let $r\in\mathcal S = \{0,\ldots, R\}$ where $R$ is the maximum number of knot locations. For the prior specification of $r$, we specify a truncated Poisson distribution:

$$p(r)\propto\frac{\lambda^{r} \exp(-\lambda)}{r!}\mathbf{1}_{\{0,\ldots,R\}}(r),$$

where a smaller value of $\lambda$ penalizes for a large number of basis functions and hence results in a more parsimonious model. For a given $r$, the knot locations $\boldsymbol k_i$ are taken to be randomly uniformly selected with state space the candidate knot locations $\mathcal R = \{\boldsymbol k_1 ,\ldots, \boldsymbol k_R\}$, where $\boldsymbol k_1 ,\ldots, \boldsymbol k_R$ are specified to be equidistantly spread over $\mathcal D$. Given $r$, the prior distribution for $\mathcal K(r) = \{\boldsymbol k_1,\ldots, \boldsymbol k_{r}\}$ is then given by:

$$p(\mathcal K(r)\mid r)=\frac{r!(R-r)!}{R!}$$

At each step of the RJMCMC algorithm, we propose one of three modifications to the current set of knots:

1. Add a knot (birth step): Draw a new knot $\boldsymbol k_{r+1}$ uniformly with probability $1/(R- r)$ from the set of the $R - r$ vacant knot locations. Let $\mathcal K^*= \mathcal K\cup \{\boldsymbol k_{r+1}\}$ be the proposed set of knots, which now has size $r^* = r + 1$.
2. Delete a knot (death step): Select a knot $\boldsymbol k_J$ uniformly at random from one of the $r$ current knot locations, so it is drawn with probability $1/r$. Then set $\mathcal K^*= \mathcal K \backslash \{\boldsymbol k_J\}$ and $r^* = r- 1$.
3. Move a knot: Select a knot $\boldsymbol k_J$ uniformly at random to be deleted, and then select a new location $\boldsymbol k_{r+1}$ from the vacant knot locations (i.e., where to move the old knot). This results in $\mathcal K^* = \{\boldsymbol k_{r+1}\}\cup\mathcal K\backslash\{\boldsymbol k_J\}$ and $r^* = r$.

Note that when we propose to add a knot, a corresponding basis coefficient $\delta'$ will also need to be proposed. Similarly, if we propose to delete a knot, the current basis coefficient $\delta$ will be set to $0$. If we propose to move a knot, we will propose changing the current basis coefficient from $\delta$ to $\delta'$. For the birth step, the prior ratio is given by:

\begin{align*}
\text{prior ratio}
&=\frac{\text{prior for }r+1\text{ knots}}{\text{prior for }r\text{ knots}}\times\frac{\text{prior for location of }r+1\text{ knots}}{\text{prior for location of }r\text{ knots}}\\
&\times\frac{\text{prior for proposed basis coefficient}}{\text{prior for current basis coefficient}}\\
&=\frac{p(r+1)}{p(r)}\frac{r+1}{R}\times\frac{\mathcal N(\delta';0,\tau^2)}{\mathcal N(0;0,\tau^2)}
\end{align*}

The corresponding proposal ratio is given by

\begin{align*}
\text{proposal ratio}
&=\frac{d_{r+1}(1/(r+1))}{b_{r}(1/(R-r))} \times\frac{1}{\mathcal N(\delta';0,\sigma^2)}\\
&=\frac{d_{r+1}(R-r)}{b_{r}(r+1)}\times\frac{1}{\mathcal N(\delta';0,\sigma^2)}\\
\end{align*}

where $\sigma^2$ is the proposal variance for $\delta$. Similar logic can be applied to the death step and the move step. The acceptance probability for the proposed set of knot locations is then $\min\{1,\alpha\}$ where

\begin{equation}
\alpha=\frac{\pi(\mathcal K^*,\boldsymbol\delta^*\mid\mathbf Z)Q(\mathcal K^*,\mathcal K)}{\pi(\mathcal K,\boldsymbol\delta\mid\mathbf Z)Q(\mathcal K,\mathcal K^*)}
\end{equation}

with proposal ratio given by

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathcal Q(\mathcal K^*,\mathcal K)}{\mathcal Q(\mathcal K,\mathcal K_k^*)}=\begin{cases}
\frac{d_{r+1}(R-r)}{b_{r}(r+1)}\times\frac{1}{\mathcal N(\delta';0,\sigma^2)},&r^*=r+1\\
\frac{b_{r-1}(r)}{d_{r}(R-r+1)}\times\mathcal N(\delta;0,\sigma^2),&r^*=r-1\\
1,&r^*=r
\end{cases}\end{equation}

Currently, I am specifying the probability of adding, deleting, and moving a knot to be 1/3 for all $r$. However, I am interested in letting these probabilities adapt to the data. For example, if the predictions are highly variable, we may favor adding a knot. Would I be violating any "rules" (e.g., detailed balance, reversibility) if I started the Markov chain with $b_r=d_r=\eta_r=1/3$ and then changed these probabilities (possibly at each step) during the MCMC algorithm?

Comment: I don't know enough to answer your question as-is but I have worked with RJMCMC in the past and I have always tended to do short runs with various choices of parameters, which I then discard and do long runs with parameters that give reasonable acceptance rate, mixing etc..

Comment: Changing the fractions $b_r,d_r,\eta_r$ from $(1/3,1/3,1/3)$ is correct if the ratio of the fractions is added to the acceptance probability function. Adapting from earlier simulations is not in general valid.

Comment: So it would be valid as long as I update the corresponding acceptance probability? For example, suppose I change the probabilities to (1/4, 1/2, /1/4) after a burnin of 1000. Then the acceptance probability for the birth step would need to be changed to $\frac{1/2(R-r)}{1/4(r+1)}\times\frac{1}{\mathcal N(\delta';0,\sigma^2)}$?

Comment: Or would I need to fix these probabilities for the entire chain?